# How to databind between two datacomponent?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material to create an image selector using `<mat-button-toggle>` and `mat-badge`. `<mat-button-toggle>` contains the image that the user can select and the `mat-badge` will overlay a green checkmark when the `<mat-button-toggle>` is in a `selected` state. When the image is de-selected, the green checkmark is hidden/removed from the image.

How do I databind `mat-badge`'s `matBadgeHidden` property to `<mat-button-toggle>`'s `selected` property? In other words, how do I get this to work `matBadgeHidden="!selected"`

**Source code**

```
<mat-button-toggle-group 
  #group="matButtonToggleGroup" 
  multiple=true>
  <mat-button-toggle 
    *ngFor="let image of images" 
    value="image.id"  
    matBadge="✔️" 
    matBadgePosition="above after" 
    matBadgeHidden="!selected" 
    matBadgeColor="basic" 
    style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; margin:10px">
      <img src="{{image.url}}" />
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

**Links to API docs:**

1. [Button Toggle](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview)
2. [Badget](https://material.angular.io/components/badge/api)

Comment: Please create a stackblitz if posible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `matBadgeHidden` property to the `mat-button-toggle` `checked` property.

```html
<mat-button-toggle 
    #imageButton
    *ngFor="let image of images"  
    matBadge="✔️" 
    [matBadgeHidden]="!imageButton.checked">
</mat-button-toggle>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfmpx5

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!